# asp.net grid view edit and delete records

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

i am trying to use a grid view to display items from the database i also want to edit and delete these records then in the grid view, i am using the sample code on asp.net snippets

http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Simple-Insert-Select-Edit-Update-and-Delete-in-ASPNet-GridView-control.aspx

it says that The name 'GetData' does not exist in the current context

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Default10 : System.Web.UI.Page
  {

      SqlCommand comm;
      string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindData();
        }
    }

    private void BindData()
    {                                   
        comm = new SqlCommand("select EmployeeID,Name,Password" +
                       " from Employee");    

        GridView1.DataSource = GetData(comm);
        GridView1.DataBind();          
    }


    protected void EditEmployee(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        BindData();
    }
    protected void CancelEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        BindData();
    }
    protected void UpdateEmployee(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        string EmployeeID = ((Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]
                            .FindControl("lblEmployeeID")).Text;
        string Name = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]
                            .FindControl("txtName")).Text;
        string Password = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]
                            .FindControl("txtPassword")).Text;


           comm  = new SqlCommand();
           comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
           comm.CommandText = "update Employee set Name=@Name," +
                              "Password=@Password where EmployeeID=@EmployeeID;" +
                              "select EmployeeID,Name,Password from Employee";

           comm.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = EmployeeID;
           comm.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Name;
           comm.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Password;
           GridView1.EditIndex = -1;        

           GridView1.DataSource = GetData(comm);
           GridView1.DataBind();           
    }

    protected void DeleteEmployee(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnkRemove = (LinkButton)sender;

        comm = new SqlCommand();
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        comm.CommandText = "delete from  Employee where " +
                           "EmployeeID=@EmployeeID;" +
                           "select EmployeeID,Name,Password from Employee";
        comm.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value
                                                   = lnkRemove.CommandArgument;

        GridView1.DataSource = GetData(comm);
        GridView1.DataBind();            
    }
}
```

Comment: i didn't see any GetData() in your code. you have only this : GetData(comm). Where is the method declaration ?

Comment: Now Add GetData() function with your code and check

Comment: @user3395738 just check my code and replace with your complete coed..

Comment: @user3395738 tell me if u get any implementation problem with my code..

Answer (score 2):

You are using Old coding so Replace your code with my code..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Default10 : System.Web.UI.Page
  {

      SqlCommand comm;
      SqlConnection connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindData();
        }
    }

    private void BindData()
    {    
        connectionString.Open();    
        comm  = new SqlCommand("select EmployeeID,Name,Password from Employee", connectionString);                           
        DataTable dt =new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adp= new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
        adp.Fill(dt);
        connectionString.Close();
        GridView1.DataSource =dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();          
    }


    protected void EditEmployee(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        BindData();
    }
    protected void CancelEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        BindData();
    }

//you should Write this code on Rowupdating and give command name 'update' to link button
    protected void UpdateEmployee(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
//start here
        string EmployeeID = ((Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]
                            .FindControl("lblEmployeeID")).Text;
        string Name = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]
                            .FindControl("txtName")).Text;
        string Password = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]
                            .FindControl("txtPassword")).Text;

      connectionString.Open();
      comm  = new SqlCommand("update Employee set Name=@Name,Password=@Password where EmployeeID=@EmployeeID",  connectionString);

       comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", EmployeeID);
       comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);
       comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);
       comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
       connectionString.Close();
       GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
       BindData();    
//end here                
    }

//you should Write this code on RowDeleting and give command name 'delete' to link button
    protected void DeleteEmployee(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
//stat here
        string EmployeeID = ((Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]
                            .FindControl("lblEmployeeID")).Text;

       connectionString.Open();
       comm = new SqlCommand("delete from  Employee where EmployeeID=@EmployeeID", connectionString);       
       comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", lnkRemove);

       comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
       connectionString.Close();
       BindData();
//end here
   }
}
```